# ssh over ssh without confirmation

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I try to execute ssh over ssh:

```
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x1.x -A ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x2.x sudo docker inspect routed | 10.x.x.x
```

I get "Connection to 10.10.x1.x closed."

When I do it with a first "-o 'StrictHostKeyChecking" only:

```
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x1.x -A ssh 10.10.x2.x sudo docker inspect routed | 10.x.x.x
```

it's working, but I need to SSH without confirmation on two hosts, how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub key from host machine to remote machine into ~/.ssh authorized_keys.